# VIPER architecture: tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, viper-architecture

I am using VIPER and at the moment I am a bit lost. How do I setup a UITabBarController in a UINavigationController and also add viewControllers to the UITabBarController? At the moment, all of my code gets messy and crashes all the time.

I'm looking for an example in Swift 3, can somebody point me in the right directions?

Comment: Take a look to this answer, hope this helps! http://stackoverflow.com/a/37690383/1887908

Answer (score 0):

If you're lost with VIPER, I suggest you start with the sample project in SWIFT 3 from this post: https://www.ckl.io/blog/best-practices-viper-architecture.

Then, once you're familiar with the most common cases of VIPER modules, you can solve your problem:

1) Module A initializes and calls the CoreTabBarManager (Module B)

2) Each item on your tab bar will be a `submodule` of Module B. So Module B will initialize (but not call) its `submodules`.

3) When the user clicks the tab bar item, you just call the `submodule` (which have already been initialized by the CoreTabBarManager)